# How can I format datetimes to strings containing asterisks/wildcards in Python?

Tags: python, string, datetime, string-formatting

I'd like to be able to do something like `datetime(2022, 1, 1, 12, "*", "*", "*").strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")` and have it output `"20220101_***"`. How can I implement something like this?

Comment: Why not simply modify the strftime directive? Replace whatever attribute there, e.g. `"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S".replace("%H", "*")` to get an asterisk for the hour etc.

Comment: I didn't realize that would work! I was getting errors before. The issue with it is that I'd need to account for all different representations of the level I want to represent as wildcard (e.g. `%b`, `%B`, or `%m` for month). But it definitely works.